# Class design - use optionals? variants? be opaque?

Tags: c++, c++17, class-design

I want to have a class for PCI bus locations. For the sake of discussion, these come in three forms:

- [domain]:[bus]:[device].[function]
- [domain]:[bus]:[device]
- [bus]:[device].[function]

and let's say each field is a non-negative integral value (let's even say `unsigned` just to make things simple).

I'm scratching my head regarding how to define this class. I could use `std::optional`s for the domain and function fields; but then, they're not *both* optional. I could use a variant with 3 types, but then I need to define separate types, which overlap a lot. I could just hold 4 `unsigned`s and a 3-value enum for which format is in effect - but that's quite a bit of hassle, and I'd need getter and to make the class opaque. Same thing if I try to use a union somehow.

It seems like every choice I make, it's going to be an iffy class. How can I minimize my displeasure with it?

Note: Any language standard version is ok for the answer, although I doubt C++20 would give you anything.

Comment: You may assign an "anonymous" / "predefined" domain property to the last option, same for "function"

Comment: @umlcat: I'm not sure I understand; please elaborate.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. Why exactly do you need your tuple to be "opaque"?

Comment: @Kit.: 1. I don't need it to be opaque. I just want to put this information in a class - and prevent users of this class from having to run checks of "did I actually read a valid field or is it not actually in use with the chosen location format". 2. It's not a tuple.

Comment: 2. Being duck-typed, it's a tuple, i.e. a member of the Cartesian product of (optional<domain>, bus, device, optional<function>). 1. If users should care about its individual fields (and not just whether it as a whole describes a valid location in the system), why? I'm not saying that they "shouldn't", I'm saying that _why_ they should care is a vital information for developing a proper interface to it.

Comment: @Kit.: Not all elements of that cartesian product are valid PCI locations.

Comment: How about simply adding a format enum to your class? Then have a specific constructor for each of the three forms. If a user calls `function()` and the format does not include the function field, throw. Of course a user would still need to check what format the object is in beforehand, but it seems there's no way around that. Can you give some example use cases for the class? I.e. how are these values to be used?

Comment: Moreover, not all elements that are valid PCI locations on one system are valid PCI locations on another. The validity of the tuple value can be enforced by constructors; _what utility_ do you add to the users of your class by trying to enforce it in a way that is obviously more complicated even to yourself?

Comment: @Darhuuk: Maybe. But - what about the actual fields? Can you make your comment into a full-fledged answer?

Comment: @Kit.: 1. I'm working with this other library which takes PCI locations in one of these formats, so it doesn't quite matter what happens on my specific system. 2. I'm not against your suggestion per se. Will you make it into a full-fledged answer please so I have the full picture?

Answer (score 1):

Building upon my comment, I was wondering if something like this could work:

```
enum class pci_format { domain_function, domain, function };

template <pci_format E> struct tag { }; 

class pci_location {
  public:
    pci_location (tag<pci_format::domain_function>, unsigned domain, unsigned bus,
      unsigned device, unsigned function)
      : format_(pci_format::domain_function)
      , domain_(domain)
      , bus_(bus)
      , device_(device)
      , function_(function)
    { }

    // Repeat for other values of pci_format.

    pci_format format () const { return format_; }

    bool has_domain () const {
      return (format_ == pci_format::domain_function)
        or (format_ == pci_format::domain);
    }

    unsigned domain () const {
      if (not has_domain()) { throw std::runtime_error("Domain not available."); }
      return domain_;
    }

    // Repeat for other fields.

  private:
    pci_format format_;
    unsigned domain_;
    unsigned bus_;
    unsigned device_;
    unsigned function_
};
```

You would basically create a specific constructor for each PCI "format". Of course you could also store each `unsigned` as an `std::optional<unsigned>`, but that would force users to "dereference" each optional even if they knew for sure that it must contain a value.

One way or another, they'll have to check what "format" the location is in, so it seems to me that using an enum for this is more user friendly. Then users only have to check once and know exactly which fields are available.

I guess you could layer a visitor on top of all this so they can simply provide code to execute for each "format":

```
struct pci_location_visitor {
  virtual void visit (tag<pci_format::domain_function>, pci_location const & obj) = 0;
  // Repeat for other enum values.
};

// Add to pci_location:
void accept (pci_location_visitor & visitor) {
  switch (format_) {
    case pci_format::domain_function:
      return visitor.visit(tag<pci_format::domain_function>{}, *this);
    default: throw std::runtime_error("Format not supported for visitation.");
  }
}
```

Then on top of that you could create a visitor that can be constructed from a bunch of callables, i.e. lambdas, so that this all can be used like below:

```
pci_location const & loc = getIt();
auto printSomething = make_pci_location_visitor(
      [](tag<pci_format::domain_function>, pci_location const & e) { std::cout << e.domain(); }
    , [](tag<pci_format::domain>,          pci_location const & e) { std::cout << e.bus(); }
    , [](tag<pci_format::function>,        pci_location const & e) { std::cout << e.function(); }
  );
loc.accept(printSomething);
```

For an example of how such a visitor could be constructed, see the `overloaded` class in the [`std::visit` example on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

Comment: ... so, opaque immutable fields, and and a variant-ish aspect. interesting.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create strong types for `domain`, `bus`, ... and have three constructors accepting them in the proper order. The format could then simply be derived from the provided arguments. I've used something similar to [foonathan's strong typedefs](https://foonathan.net/2016/10/strong-typedefs/) with great success. I then have constructors accept such types and store the actual (i.e. unwrapped) values internally. Getters return the unwrapped value, since it seems pretty clear to me that `unsigned height ();` is going to return a height, no need to return a `height` type there.

Answer (score 0):

As requested in comments... given that I have no particular requirements how the users would prefer to use this class, given C++14, I would be doing something generic along the lines of:

```
#include <array>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class pci_location_t {
public:
    struct dbdf {
        unsigned int domain;
        unsigned int bus;
        unsigned int device;
        unsigned int function;
    };
    struct dbd {
        unsigned int domain;
        unsigned int bus;
        unsigned int device;
    };
    struct bdf {
        unsigned int bus;
        unsigned int device;
        unsigned int function;
    };

    pci_location_t(dbdf v) : domain(v.domain), bus(v.bus), device(v.device), function(v.function) {}
    pci_location_t(dbd v) : domain(v.domain), bus(v.bus), device(v.device), function(INVALID) {}
    pci_location_t(bdf v) : domain(INVALID), bus(v.bus), device(v.device), function(v.function) {}

    template <typename dbdf_f, typename dbd_f, typename bdf_f>
    auto visit(dbdf_f dbdf_fun, dbd_f dbd_fun, bdf_f bdf_fun) const {
        if (domain == INVALID) {
            if (function == INVALID) {
                throw std::domain_error("Wrong PCI location format");
            }
            return bdf_fun(bdf{bus, device, function});
        } else if (function == INVALID) {
            return dbd_fun(dbd{domain, bus, device});
        } else {
            return dbdf_fun(dbdf{domain, bus, device, function});
        }
    }

private:
    friend pci_location_t invalid_location();
    pci_location_t() : domain(INVALID), bus(INVALID), device(INVALID), function(INVALID) {}

    const static unsigned int INVALID = UINT_MAX;

    unsigned int domain;
    unsigned int bus;
    unsigned int device;
    unsigned int function;
};

pci_location_t invalid_location() { return pci_location_t{}; }

int main() {
    std::array<pci_location_t, 4> locations = {
        pci_location_t(pci_location_t::dbdf{1, 2, 3, 4}),
        pci_location_t(pci_location_t::dbd{1, 2, 3}),
        pci_location_t(pci_location_t::bdf{2, 3, 4}),
        invalid_location()
    };
    try {
        for (auto& l : locations) {
            l.visit(
                [] (auto dbdf) {
                    std::cout << dbdf.domain << ":" << dbdf.bus << ":" << dbdf.device << "." << dbdf.function << std::endl;
                },
                [] (auto dbd) {
                    std::cout << dbd.domain << ":" << dbd.bus << ":" << dbd.device << std::endl;
                },
                [] (auto bdf) {
                    std::cout << bdf.bus << ":" << bdf.device << "." << bdf.function << std::endl;
                }
            );
        }
        std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(you can check it on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b9bcece4eee6a35)).

Feel free to use optionals or a separate format field if you don't like special values.

Comment: I feel a bit of repetitiveness here... But perhaps more importantly - I'm not too happy about users having to explicitly form dbdf's, dbd's and bdf's for construction.

Comment: C++ has no named arguments. You can let the users form `pci_location_t::domain` etc., though, and feed them as arguments to a variadic template constructor. The good part of this code, though, is that the compiler will optimize most of it away (won't do extra copies of `domain`, `bus`, `device`, `function` values in the constructors and in lambdas, won't do any function calls except to the `ostream` itself, etc.).

Comment: Anyway, as I said, if you have some requirements from the user's perspective, you should have started with them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make both the domain and the function optional (I don't really care how, as long as it's effective), and just enforce the only-one-missing condition as a class invariant. That is, only the functions that can change any of the fields need to perform the check and signal possible errors back to the user. No need to bloat your code with variants, or with dynamically interpreted `unsigned int` arrays. KISS.

Comment: That means making the fields private, but providing setters and getters with the enforcement? Also, the Monica Cellio campaign has ended.

Comment: @einpoklum Yes.